# Aren't we using jsss these days?

Tags: javascript, css

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets

> Javascript Style Sheets were only supported by Netscape 4.x (4.0–4.8) but no later versions. No other web browser integrated JSSS.
>
> Using JavaScript code as a stylesheet, JSSS styles individual element by modifying properties of the document.tags object. For example, the CSS:
>
> h1 { font-size: 20pt; }
>
> is equivalent to the JSSS:
>
> document.tags.H1.fontSize = "20pt";
>
> JSSS element names are case sensitive.

But we still use like this but why is this saying jsss  is not integrated? So, what are using these days?

Comment: Looking at usage example, it's a good thing that it's never been implemented.

Comment: In which browser do you have a `document.tags` object? The current way may seem similar from a syntax point of view, but is organized quite differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But we still use like this...

No, we don't. (In your browser's console, type `typeof document.tags` and see what you get... :-) )

We use:

- CSS stylesheets (`<style>...</style>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`)
- [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) objects if we need to manipulate those styles from JavaScript
- The `style` property of elements if we need to manipulate just that element's style from JavaScript:

  ```
  document.getElementById("some-element").style.fontSize = "20pt";
  ```

Those are entirely different things from the old JSSS.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing *JavaScript which manipulates CSS through the DOM* with *JSSS*. They are distinct things.

The syntax of JSSS is JavaScript (hence the name) but the means of accessing elements is different (it doesn't use DOM). (And JSS isn't dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understand your question, but if you're asking how you can edit styles from Javascript in a way that's supported by most (if not all browsers), you can either set them inline a DOM element using the style property, or inject a stylesheet into the browser lazily.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style
https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS

Answer (score 0):

I think the distinction you're missing here is that JSSS sets styles via `document.tags`, rather than directly on the element itself (or via the [`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule) method).

In every modern browser, you'll see that `document.tags` is `undefined`.